waitForUrl times out using playwright
I'm using the following code
await this.shareFeedbackBtn().click();
await this.page.waitForURL("https://community.test.com/**");

Error: page.waitForURL: Test timeout of 120000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for navigation to "**/community.test.com/**" until "load"
============================================================

When shareFeedbackBtn is clicked, it opens a new tab. I want to check the url of the new tab navigates to https://community.test.com/.... but I get the error above.
Can someone please help?
Is it because it opens a new tab that there's an error?

This still needs a [mcve]--it's the first time you mentioned it opens in a new tab. Why not improve the same question from 45 minutes ago?

Since it's a new tab - you need to get it
  const event = page.waitForEvent("popup");
  await this.shareFeedbackBtn().click();
  const newPage = await event;
  await expect(newPage).toHaveURL(/community/);
  // or yours
  await newPage.waitForURL("https://community.test.com/**");

As usual - Playwright Docs has it all :)
